# Bash Script : Unwanted Output

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have this simple bash script:
I run ns simulator on each file passed in argument where last argument is some text string to search for.

```
#!/bin/bash

nsloc="/home/ashish/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/ns"
temp="temp12345ashish.temp"

j=1

for file in "$@"
do
        if [ $j -lt $# ]
        then
                let j=$j+1

                `$nsloc $file > $temp 2>&1`

                if grep -l ${BASH_ARGV[0]} $temp
                then
                        echo "$file Successful"

                fi

        fi
done
```

I expected:

```
   file1.tcl Successful
```

I am getting:

```
   temp12345ashish.temp
   file1.tcl Successful
```

When i run the simulator command myself on the terminal i do not get the file name to which output is directed.

I am not getting from where this first line of output is getting printed.
Please explain it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `man grep`, and see specifically the explanation of the `-l` option.

In your script (above), you are using `-l`, so grep is telling you (as instructed) the filename where the match occurred.

If you don't want to see the filename, don't use `-l`, or use `-q` with it also.  Eg:

```
grep -ql ${BASH_ARGV[0]} $temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Just silence the grep:

```
 if grep -l ${BASH_ARGV[0]} $temp &> /dev/null
```